# How to create a variable which changes randomly and smoothly?

Tags: random-variables

I want to create a variable which is assumed to be the acceleration of a car. I assume it should has zero mean and normal distribution. But the acceleration cannot change rapidly. How do I make it change smoothly (slowly) overtime?

Comment: Integrate Brownian motion?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I don't know if it must be that complicated. You can imagine that when you drive a car, the speed can't be the same overtime. So the acceleration should be slowly changing around 0. I just want a variable having that property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I assume it should has zero mean and normal distribution. But the acceleration cannot change rapidly.

In signal processing, that amounts to generate a stochastic process with low frequency. The simplest way is a AR(1) (autoregresive process) of the form

$$X[n]= \alpha X[n-1] + \beta e[n]$$

where $e[n]$ is zero mean white gaussian noise, (typically generated by a pseudorandom number generator),  $0<\alpha<1$ is a "memory" parameter that tunes the cut-off frequency and $\beta>0$ is a factor that determines the variance.

Comment: This is exact what I want. Thank you very much ^.^

Comment: you're welcome. BTW, notice that with $\alpha=1$ this indeed amounts to "integrate brownian motion" (cf Henning Makholm comment), with $\alpha <1$ we only add a decreasing exponential window

Answer (score 0):

So basically you are looking for a distribution that changes smoothly. There are many, take the Cauchy distribution with mean $0$ and the scale parameter near $2$ to $3$

Answer (score 0):

$$
a_{n + 1} = a_{n} + 10^{-6}\sigma
$$
where $\displaystyle{\sigma}$ take values $\displaystyle{\pm 1}$ with probability $\displaystyle{1 \over 2}$ each.

---

I imagine you are thinking in a computer simulation so you *can play* by changing the $\displaystyle{\sigma}$ prefactor which is actualy $\displaystyle{10^{-6}}$.

Comment: The problem with this is that $a_n$ is not stable (nor stationary). A better way is to add a multiplier $a_{n + 1} = \alpha a_{n} + \beta \sigma$ where $0< \alpha < 1$ (in terms of Autoregresive processes, this would amount to move the pole inside the unit circle)

Comment: @leonbloy Thanks. I didn't think in that posibility. This is somehow new for me.